# Is there a way in R to rank categorical variable (of characters) into ranked ordinal data?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a list of character strings, say 
`alphabets = c(a, b, c, d,..., z)` and I would like to get the index of this list as a new column in a `data.frame`.

e.g. `(b, a, c, d, e, g)` would yield `(2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case for `match`

```
x <- c("b", "a", "c", "d", "e", "g")

match(x, letters)
#[1] 2 1 3 4 5 7
```

Or `sapply` with `grep` returning a named `int` vector

```
sapply(x, grep, letters)
#b a c d e g
#2 1 3 4 5 7
```

---

### Two comments:

1. *"I have a list of character strings"* Be precise with class names of objects! `alphabets = c("a", "b", "c", "d")` is a `character` vector, not a `list`.
2. `letters` is a built-in constant which returns the 26 lower-case letters (of the Roman alphabet) as a `character` vector. See `?letters` for details.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you need is to convert the character vector to a factor:

```
alphabets = c("b", "a", "c", "d", "e", "g")
#convert to class factor with the order define by the levels option
alphabets<-factor(alphabets, levels=letters)

#display the values
as.numeric(alphabets)
#[1] 2 1 3 4 5 7
```

Comment: Specifically, since the OP asked for "ranked ordinal data", it would be best to use an `ordered` factor - `as.numeric(ordered(x, levels=letters))`